# Is someone able to understand what kind of division algorithm is implemented in this code?

Tags: floating-point, vhdl, division

I have this code implementing a floating point division algorithm in VHDL, I have to write a C version of it. I am struggling to understand what type of algorithm is used in this code. The `SelFunctionTable` is provided with all the links (even if they are not very clear to me)

I have done some research about division algorithms but I haven't really come up with an answer, I don't understand the padding alternatives nor the reasons of the prescaling. The process is then repeated `n` times of course. Is there anyone who can at least help in classifying this algorithm so that I can look up for it? 
Thanks a lot

```
fX <= "1" & X(22 downto 0);
fY <= "1" & Y(22 downto 0); 

-- Prescaling
with fY (22 downto 21)  select 
  prescaledfY <= 
     ("0" & fY & "0") + (fY & "00") when "00",
     ("00" & fY) + (fY & "00") when "01",
     fY &"00" when others;
with fY (22 downto 21)  select 
  prescaledfX <= 
     ("00" & fX & "0") + ("0" & fX & "00") when "00",
     ("000" & fX) + ("0" & fX & "00") when "01",
     "0" & fX &"00" when others;
w9 <=  "00" & prescaledfX;
sel9 <= w9(28 downto 24) & prescaledfY(23 downto 22);
SelFunctionTable9: selFunction7_4_F10_uid4
  port map ( X => sel9,
             Y => q9_copy5);
q9 <= q9_copy5; -- output copy to hold a pipeline register if needed
w9pad <= w9 & '0';
with q9(1 downto 0)  select  
w8fulla <= 
  w9pad - ("0000" & prescaledfY)            when "01",
  w9pad + ("0000" & prescaledfY)            when "11",
  w9pad + ("000" & prescaledfY & "0")       when "10",
  w9pad                     when others;

with q9(3 downto 1)  select  
fYdec8 <= 
  ("00" & prescaledfY & "00")           when "001" | "010" | "110"| 
  ("0" & prescaledfY & "000")           when "011"| "100",
  (29 downto 0 => '0')when others;
with q9(3)  select 
w8full <= 
  w8fulla - fYdec8          when '0',
  w8fulla + fYdec8          when others;
w8 <= w8full(26 downto 0) & "00";
sel8 <= w8(28 downto 24) & prescaledfY(23 downto 22);
SelFunctionTable8: selFunction7_4_F10_uid4
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but in Knuth's division algorithm, the divisor must be shifted left until all leading zero bits are removed. The dividend must be shifted exactly the same number of positions. The numbers like 22 downto 0 remind me of the bits of a float, but I could be wrong there. ISTM this simply sets things up for floating point division, where the SelFunction things seem to actually do the division. ISTM that this is almost impossible to convert to C without knowledge what the selFunction stuff does exactly and perhaps even **with** that knowledge. This is a hardware description language.